# How to avoid redundancy in MipMap For Locale

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, mipmaps

I have to use different mipmap based on locale of user. But some of them are same. Example, en_US and en_GB need same launcher icons but en_IN needs different.

I know the way is to create multiple mipmaps (anydpi-v26,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi - for resolution purpose) for each local Ex: mipmap-b+en+IN-anydpi-v26, mipmap-b+en+US-anydpi-v26, mipmap-b+en+GB-anydpi-v26 etc and multiply by 6 times for all resolutions. But since US and GB need same resource, how to avoid this redundancy?